# jquery's ajax method

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type:"get",
    url:"/test/api/?u="+u,
    dataType:"json",
    data:"",
    success:function result(data){
            $("#show").html(data);
        $("#show").show();
       }
});
```

i don't understand the above code well, especially the `success` part. i don't know what will be passed to the parameter  `data`. expect someone can explain it to me. thank you.

Comment: May I suggest reading the documentation on the `$.ajax` method? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

`data` will hold the content returned by the url that you sent the request to. If the url you are posting to is another HTML page, the code for the entire page will be stored in `data` for example.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `data` is a javascript object, like a dictionary, list, int, string, etc. because the `dataType` is `json` and jQuery auto-convert the response returned by the url to a javascript object.

Comment: The line means: Select the element whose ID is "show" and attempt to replace its HTML content (e.g. innerHTML) with the contents of variable `data`. Presumably `data` is a string, and more specifically a string that represents HTML markup.

Comment: @CoryLarson +1. But it doesn't make sense to use json in this case.